# How to color an excel cell with excel js

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I'm creating an excel spreadsheet using the excel js library, and I need to color a cell. How can I do this?
I know that you can change the color of the text using cell.font. Is there a property for cell color?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use:

```
var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var cell = sheet.getCell("A1");
cell.format.fill.color = "green";
```

Replace green with your color (color name, hex, or rgb)

Comment: I use typescript and get the error: Property 'format' does not exist on type 'Cell'